# scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError exception

Tags: scala, sbt, sorm

I am stuck on a problem and can't resolve it. 
Today, I get an error while building the project. This error is described in topic:
[Why do I get conflicting cross-version in sbt on one environment but not another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088274/why-do-i-get-conflicting-cross-version-in-sbt-on-one-environment-but-not-another)

As I understand the new version of scala was released (2.12.0-M1) and dependencies was broken.
The answer on this question is to override "org.scala-lang" and "scala-compiler" dependency using code:

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

My scalaVersion is `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"`.
This resolved the problem with building the project.
The server runs successfully, but when I try call `DB` object (that extends `Instance`) to perform a query I get an exception:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:523) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at models.dao.UserDAO$.getUser(UserDAO.scala:32) ~[classes/:na]
        at controllers.User$$anonfun$login$1.apply(User.scala:82) ~[classes/:na]
        at controllers.User$$anonfun$login$1.apply(User.scala:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:433) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:432) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed: cannot initialize the compiler due to java.lang.VerifyError: scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.liftedTree1$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:344) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.compiler$lzycompute(ToolBoxFactory.scala:330) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.compiler(ToolBoxFactory.scala:329) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.liftedTree2$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:356) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:354) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.liftedTree1$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:334) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.compiler$lzycompute(ToolBoxFactory.scala:330) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.compiler(ToolBoxFactory.scala:329) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.liftedTree2$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:356) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:354) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

I think it is related to scala update and configuration issues, because yesterday I worked with the same services without any exceptions.

My `build.sbt`:

```
name := """XXXX"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.18",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.7",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-core" % "1.4.2",
  "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-canvas" % "1.4.2",
  "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-filters" % "1.4.2",
  "com.notnoop.apns" % "apns" % "1.0.0.Beta6",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: This might be specific to your project, so it's hard to say *why* without full `build.sbt`, but *what* happens is that you have several versions of scala-compiler.jar in classpath

Comment: talking about linked question, did you try to clear caches, targets, sbt's project targets?

Comment: Thank you, I will think about why in my classpath there are several scala-compiler.jar. Also I updated the task with the `build.sbt` content

Comment: Deleted `$HOME/.ivy2/cache`, and target folders, but no success, same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. Increasing scalaVersion to 2.11.6 solved it.

Comment: I resolved this earlier by extracting SORM from `build.sbt` and adding tricky hacked sorm.jar file as external library. Now I have come back to simpler solution with SORM in `libraryDependencies`, that is good. Thank you!

Comment: I am using 2.11.12 and I am still getting this error.