# sorm version causing activator to fail compile

Tags: scala, playframework, sorm

I have the following in my build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.11.1" % "test",
  ("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" %    scalaVersion.value).exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-parser-combinators"),

)
```

If I add:

```
"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.15"
```

It still works. IF I go to 0.3.18 it fails.

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/home/daveh/play-scala/}root:
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.11, _2.12.0-M1
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators _2.11, _2.12.0-M1
```

Is this to be expected?

Comment: I got kind of the same exception, the post here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30088758/1948319 helped me out.